# taking input to the .c file using pyqt

Tags: python, c, python-extensions

I have created a c program which requires an input (through scanf). Then I created the .so file and called that in a python script, so that when I run the script, input will be asked in the terminal. But when I run the python program, the terminal hangs.

**Please note**:

1. My c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int open(void)
{
    char input[20];
    scanf("input = %s\n",&input);
    printf("\n%s\n","input");
}
```

2. Command I used for compiling the code

```
gcc -c usb_comm.c
```

3.Creating .so file

```
gcc -shared -o libhello.so usb_comm.o
```

4.Relevant section of python program

Loading the .so file

```
from ctypes import cdll
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/vineeshvs/Dropbox/wel/workspace/Atmel/libhello.so')
```

Calling the function defined in the c program

```
mydll.scanf("%c",mydll.open())
```

Thanks for listening :)

Comment: You may want to read about the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), especially its [`Popen` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). Then re-create your C module as an ordinary program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mydll.open()` call scanf. Why do you call scanf in Python?

Just call `mydll.open()` only:

```
mydll.open()
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void open(void)
{
    char input[20];
    printf("input = "); // If you want prompt
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("\n%s\n", input);
}
```

Comment: I replaced the line `mydll.scanf("%c",mydll.open())` with `mdll.open()`.  But still the terminal hangs and doesn't ask for the input

Comment: @vineeshvs, You are misunderstanding about scanf. scanf does not prompt user.

Comment: Then which command would you suggest to take input from user?

Comment: tried the code. It prints `input =` and then waits for input. When I type something (for eg: sdf), it shows the following error `No command 'sdaf' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sadf' from package 'sysstat' (main)
 Command 'sdf' from package 'sdf' (universe)
sdaf: command not found

[2]+  Stopped                 python first_program.py
`

Comment: @vineeshvs, I can't reproduce the error. [See this screencast that I just created](http://ascii.io/a/4501).